# Adding or changing more than one texture in OpenGL Shader object - Qt/Cpp/OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm looking for a solution to add or change a texture (not mixing several, it's quite simple) within a single Shader object in OpenGL. For example, given an array of vertices that make up a house, you could use a separate image file to apply the window textures, another to cover the roof, and another to cover the walls.

I currently implement the texture overlay like this and it works, but it limits me to one texture file for the entire object, I can only manipulate the coordinates (position of texture), but it doesn't seem like a scalable solution to me.

[Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9fpb.png)

Project is written in Qt.

```
void widgetClass::initializeGL()
{
 float r, g, b, a = 1.0f;
 initializeOpenGLFunctions();

 shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/vertexShader.vsh");
 shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/fragmentShader.fsh");
 shaderProgram.link();
 
 vertices << QVector3D(-0.5, -0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5) // Front
             << QVector3D( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5, -0.5,  0.5)
             << QVector3D( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5,  0.5, -0.5) // Back
             << QVector3D(-0.5,  0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5)
             << QVector3D(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5, -0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5) // Left
             << QVector3D(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5,  0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)
             << QVector3D( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5) // Right
             << QVector3D( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5)
             << QVector3D(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5) // Top
             << QVector3D( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5,  0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5)
             << QVector3D(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5) << QVector3D( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5) // Bottom
             << QVector3D( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5, -0.5,  0.5) << QVector3D(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);

  colors << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) // Front
           << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) << QVector3D(1, 0, 0)
           << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) // Back
           << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) << QVector3D(1, 0, 0) << QVector3D(1, 0, 0)
           << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) // Left
           << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) << QVector3D(0, 1, 0)
           << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) // Right
           << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) << QVector3D(0, 1, 0) << QVector3D(0, 1, 0)
           << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) // Top
           << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) << QVector3D(0, 0, 1)
           << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) // Bottom
           << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) << QVector3D(0, 0, 1) << QVector3D(0, 0, 1);

  textureCoordinates << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1) // Front
                       << QVector2D(1, 1) << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(0, 0)
                       << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1) // Back
                       << QVector2D(1, 1) << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(0, 0)
                       << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1) // Left
                       << QVector2D(1, 1) << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(0, 0)
                       << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1) // Right
                       << QVector2D(1, 1) << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(0, 0)
                       << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1) // Top
                       << QVector2D(1, 1) << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(0, 0)
                       << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1) // Bottom
                       << QVector2D(1, 1) << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(0, 0);


 texturesBank[0] = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage(QString(":/texture.bmp")));
 texturesBank[0]->create();
 uint test = texturesBank[0]->textureId();
 texturesBank[0]->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::LinearMipMapNearest);
 texturesBank[0]->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
 texturesBank[0]->setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::Repeat);

}


void widgetClass::paintGL()
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 QMatrix4x4 mMatrix;
 QMatrix4x4 vMatrix;

 QMatrix4x4 cameraTransformation;
 cameraTransformation.rotate(alpha, 0, 1, 0); 
 cameraTransformation.rotate(beta, 1, 0, 0); 

 QVector3D cameraPosition = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 0, distance);
 QVector3D cameraUpDirection = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 1, 0);

 vMatrix.lookAt(cameraPosition, QVector3D(0, 0, 0), cameraUpDirection); 

 texturesBank[0]->bind();
 shaderProgram.bind();
 shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix);
 
 shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("vertex", vertices.constData());
 shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertex");
 
 shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("textureCoordinate", textureCoordinates.constData());
 shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("textureCoordinate");

 shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("color", colors.constData());
 shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("color");

 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
 
 shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("vertex");
 shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("textureCoordinate");
 shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("color");
 shaderProgram.release();

}


void widgetClass::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    pMatrix.setToIdentity();
    pMatrix.perspective(60.0, (float) w / (float) h, 0.001, 1000);
    //pMatrix.perspective(100.0, (float) w / (float) h, 0.001, 1000);

    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

And my shaders codes:

vertexShader.vsh

```
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
in vec4 vertex;
in vec2 textureCoordinate;
in vec4 color;

out vec2 varyingTextureCoordinate;
out vec4 varyingColor;
void main(void)
{
    varyingColor = color;
    varyingTextureCoordinate = textureCoordinate;
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vertex;
}
```

fragmentShader.fsh

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
in vec2 varyingTextureCoordinate;
in vec4 varyingColor;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main(void)
{
   fragColor = texture2D(texture, varyingTextureCoordinate);
}
```

- I tried to create some "sampler2D" and multiply by an array of 0's and 1's in the shader, but it's not very efficient and unprofessional imo.
- I tried messing with the texture coordinates and this option is the most sensible so far, but it also causes the file to grow large as the project grows.
- I tried creating an array and changing bindings in the process, but I'm probably doing it wrong because it had no effect.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a single Sampler2D to access different textures, Have a look at [Texture Atlasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas).

You can effectively pack all of your textures in a single, big textures, change the individual UV coordinates of the vertices in order to have them point at the right texture *in* the atlas and save a lot of performance/have reusable shader code.

I am not an expert in this but I think that there are programs that can stitch textures together to create an atlas, a quick search pointer me to [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/download), you might want to start here.

Comment: Thenks for Your reply! As described I know about option with UV, but I am looking for more scalable solution. If I have 5 textures this option is nice, but what, when I have 1000 textures? :)

Comment: In general, you should create a texture atlas for each model/mesh/gameObject, or basically for anything you are currently trying to render, this can be solved by the Texture Atlas, once you are done rendering that object, you unbind the VBO, unbind the texture atlas from that channel, bind the next object's VBO, bind the new texture atlas on the channel, and do another draw call.

There is no sense in having anything in a single object, at some point you are going to have to manage each object's data through a Model/Mesh class so that you can automate this Binding/Unbinding work

Comment: Thanks! Now, theoretically everything is clear for me! Unbind is what i want, but I don't find it yet

Comment: You can find informations (and search for) OpenGL functions such as unbind [here](https://docs.gl/), moreover, if you [bind](https://docs.gl/gl4/glBindTexture) a texture to a target that previously had another texture bound, it will overwrite it without need to unbind the previous one, if my answer clarified your doubt be sure to mark it as correct, thank you!